# Hacer función concurrente en Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, hilos

Tengo la siguiente función:

```
import threading
import time
from datetime import datetime

def primera():
    contador = 0
    while contador < 10:
        print("Primera")
        print(datetime.now())
        time.sleep(5)

def segunda():
    contador = 0
    while contador < 10:
        print("Segunda")
        print(datetime.now())
        time.sleep(5)

hilo1 = threading.Thread(target=primera)
hilo2 = threading.Thread(target=segunda)

contar = 0
while contar < 10:
    hilo1.start()
    hilo2.start()
```

Funciona bien, pero quisiera tener la siguiente función:

```
import threading
import time
from datetime import datetime

def primera(palabra):
    contador = 0
    while contador < 10:
        print(palabra)
        print(datetime.now())
        time.sleep(5)

hilo1 = threading.Thread(target=primera('primera'))
hilo2 = threading.Thread(target=primera('Segunda'))

contar = 0
while contar < 10:
    hilo1.start()
    hilo2.start()
```

Pero esta función no hace lo que deseo, primero ejecuta 10 veces el `hilo1` y después 10 veces el `hilo2`. ¿Cómo hago para que ejecute el *hilo 1 y 2* al mismo tiempo pero con parámetros distintos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas pasar los argumentos a la función **primera** cuando creas el hilo:

```
import threading
import time
from datetime import datetime

def primera(palabra):
   contador = 0
   while contador < 10:
       print(palabra)
       print(datetime.now())
       time.sleep(5)

hilo1 = threading.Thread(target=primera, args=('Primera',))
hilo2 = threading.Thread(target=primera, args=('Segunda',))

contar = 0
while contar < 10:
    hilo1.start()
    hilo2.start()
```

Aunque no garantiza el orden de ejecución de los hilos, para eso necesitas **locks** o **semaforos**